# Универсальные потоки чтения/записи java

Tags: java

Есть небольшая клиент-серверная программка, клиенты могут делать запросы на получение списка файлов и их загрузку. Сейчас программа нормально пишет только текстовые файлы, используются потоки `DataInputStream` и `DataOutputStream`.(оборачивают `FileInputStream` и `OutputStream` соответственно).

Всё содержимое файлов считывается обычным `FileInputStream`, но перед отправкой записывается в строку, что не есть хорошо. Какие потоки лучше использовать для чтения записи содержимого? При условии что мы не знаем с каким типом файла придется работать.

И в каком виде лучше передавать данные через tcp/ip?

Comment: Читайте обычным `BufferedInputStream` в `byte[]`, потом отправляйте байты в сокет. Ничего сложного.

Comment: Так и попробовал сделать, теперь выскакивает malformed input around byte 0

Comment: вы понимаете, что без примера неработающего кода вам сложно будет помочь?

Comment: Человек, скажу, никто нормальный данные не передает через поток обьектов. Это 1.очень медленно, 2.кучу мусора переходит через сокет а то дополнительные расходы на cpu, интернет.

Comment: И какое отношение File потоки имеют до сокет потоков? Там обычный набор байтов из InputStream и отправка данных через OutputStream. Займитесь чем-то другим.